# Jquery file upload in rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi everyone i am following the video tutorial for Jquery File Upload at http://railscasts.com/episodes/381-jquery-file-upload and am stuck.  I after upload images my render partial does not refresh, it adds the new image and all other images under the image that was already attached. So if I add two images to a new item it shows the first image, then renders the partial again with the first image and the second image under the first so there are 3 photos in total.

Here is my create.js.erb

```
<% if @photo.new_record? %>
  alert("Failed to upload photo: <%= j @photo.errors.full_messages.join(', ').html_safe %>");
<% else %>
  $("#photos").append("<%=j render @photo %>");
<% end %>
```

Here is my render from my show page.

```
<div id="photos">
    <%= render 'photos/photo' %>
</div>
```

Here is my /photos/_photos.html.erb partial

```
<h2>Images</h2>
<div class="photo">
<% @rental.photos.each do |photo| %>
  <p>
    <strong>Photo:</strong>
    <%= image_tag photo.image_url.to_s %>
    </script>   
  </p>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

Here is my Photos Controller create

```
 def create
    @rental = Rental.find(params[:rental_id])
    @photo = @rental.photos.create(params[:photo].permit(:image))

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Here is my photos.js.jcoffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('#new_photo').fileupload(replaceFileInput: false,
    paramName: 'photo[image]')


    dataType: "script"
    add: (e, data) ->
      types = /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
      file = data.files[0]
      if types.test(file.type) || types.test(file.name)
        data.context = $(tmpl("template-upload", file))
        $('#new_photo').append(data.context)
        data.submit()
      else
        alert("#{file.name} is not a gif, jpeg, or png image file")
    progress: (e, data) ->
      if data.context
        progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10)
        data.context.find('.bar').css('width', progress + '%')
```

Any help would be great, I'm stuck. Thanks!

---

Thank you so much Rich Peck his answer fully solved my problem. I had to change

```
<% if @photo.new_record? %>
  alert("Failed to upload photo: <%= j @photo.errors.full_messages.join(', ').html_safe %>");
<% else %>
  $("#photos").append("<%=j render @photo %>");
<% end %>
```

To

```
<% if @photo.new_record? %>
  alert("Failed to upload photo: <%= j @photo.errors.full_messages.join(', ').html_safe %>");
<% else %>
  $("#photos").html("<%=j render @photo %>");
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def create
    @rental = Rental.find(params[:rental_id])
    @photo = @rental.photos.create(params[:photo].permit(:image))

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end
```

That's my first look at it

---

The fix was actually to use `$('#photos').html()` to replace the container. The OP was originally using `.append` to just append content to the container, which didn't work very well at all

Comment: Hi Rich, thanks for helping. I have added the respond_to my create, and no change. I thought since the Rental needs to respond_to js the controller above it might need one as but I got a ActionController::UnknownFormat when I added the same respond to the rental create action. Any Other Ideas?

Comment: Okay so the problem is either going to be that your JS is not rendering properly, or you have syntax errors in your create.js.erb. Firstly, you should take out all the current code in your create.js.erb & add a simple alert (to see if it's being called). You can call an alert like this: `alert('test');`

Comment: Hey rich, I have done what you suggested, and the alert works, so that must mean the js is not rendering properly. Is there a way to track this down?

Comment: Yep, it's just a case of working through the code to see what's causing the problem. I'd start with <% if @photo.new_record? %>alert('new')<% else %>alert('bad')<% end %>

Comment: Your structure is okay - if the alert works, it means there is a problem with the actual code contained in the js.erb file you're working with :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me out. So is this something I can change? Or should I just try a completely different a gem for uploading multiple files.

Comment: No!! Paperclip is the best. It's just in your create.js.erb file - if you want to go to chat, let me know

Comment: Hey Rich, I would like that very much. I cannot start one as I do not have enough reputation. Also this tutorial used carrierwave.

Comment: Says you can't come into chat because you don't have enough rep :( Let's see if someone will upvote your question to give you the rep! Carrierwave & Paperclip are both great! I believe the problem is with your JS

Comment: Awesome, I will check back in a bit to see if anything has changed. In the mean time would my photos.js.coffee file help at all?

Comment: Your photo.js.coffee isn't going to be able to handle the callback from Ajax

Comment: Have you got skype or something we could go to?

Comment: for sure my skype is blakegeist

Comment: Hey Rich, may I get your skype name? I still do not have enough rep to join a chat. Thanks.

Comment: Just re-sent my request :)